# Reading a json file with a JavaScript loop and post the result

Tags: javascript, json, loops, render

I need to read a .json file with a JavaScript loop, and I have no idea how that is supposed to work. After I read the .json file I'm supposed to post the things I read out, on a HTML file.

I'm not worried about the HTML part, I'm more worried about the JavaLoop. I have tried multiple things now and I also read the questions of other users regarding the loop.

```
"source": "/var/log/apache2/git.1234.de-443-access.json",
"data": {
    "http_code": 204,
    "pid": "-",
    "request_id": "-",
    "log_level": "-",
    "body_size": 0,
    "host": "git.1234.de",
    "peer_ip": "10.200.13.212",
    "duration": 1693,
    "source": "-",
    "client_port": "-",
    "error_message": "-",
    "client_ip": "10.200.13.333",
```

Above you can see the .json file and for example I want to get only the client IPs, what do I have to do?
How is my Javascript loop supposed to read it?

Comment: have you been able to read the data from the file? or do you also want to know how to read the file data?

Comment: Hey Devashish, so far I havent been able to read the data from the file, to be honest I havent come far at all..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out this , you will get the `client-ip`

```
    var obj = { 
     "source": "/var/log/apache2/git.1234.de-443-access.json",
     "data": {
        "http_code": 204,
        "pid": "-",
        "request_id": "-",
        "log_level": "-",
        "body_size": 0,
        "host": "git.1234.de",
        "peer_ip": "10.200.13.212",
        "duration": 1693,
        "source": "-",
        "client_port": "-",
        "error_message": "-",
        "client_ip": "10.200.13.333",
    }
   }

//for client_ip ,
var client_ip = obj.data.client_ip;
console.log(obj.data.client_ip)
```

Comment: Don't do it in comments, either - users are generally free to vote and accept as they see fit

Comment: Sorry for it sir . @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in Node

```
const fs = require('fs')
    fs.readFile('./demo.json', 'utf8', (err, jsonString) => {
        try {
                const file= JSON.parse(jsonString)
                console.log("Client IP:", file.data.client_ip) 
        } catch(err) {
                console.log('Error parsing JSON string:', err)
            }
        })
```